# Scale MNIST-Data to [-0.9, 0.9]

Tags: neural-networks, python, backpropagation

I'm programming a neural network for MNIST-Recognition. My net has a pretty good performance, with accuracy > 98% on test set. But the training is very slow. So I thought it would be faster if I scale the data set to the range [-0.9, 0.9] (I use tanh as activation function).

The net trains faster with scaled data but the accuracy is now only 97%. I don't know why the performance is worse with scaled data, can you explain that to me?

Comment: 97%... of what?

Comment: 97% on MNIST test set. I stop training when I get stuck 20 epochs on validation data.

Comment: You're quoting a percentage, but there's no context for what it refers to. Is that 97% an accuracy? A Brier score? Something else? 97% probability that the Bears win the World Series

Comment: 97% percentage right prediction of the digits. Sorry for my imprecision.

Comment: How do you know this isn't purely random? How many patterns are there in your test set? Can you determine which exact patters switch from correctly classified to incorrectly classified when you scale?

Comment: The MNIST-Test Set is 10'000 Images. I don't think that this is random...No I haven't tried to find out which patterns switch, I thought maybe my "trick" is just a bad idea.

Comment: While it's often true that scaling improves training time, it's not clear that scaling is the culprit here -- the ANN response surface is notoriously nonconvex, so it's plausible that training the model again just found a different location to terminate.

Comment: @ General Abrial: Okay thanks. So is it worth to try scaling with other ranges or is it just a waste of time?

Comment: Scaling is unlikely to hurt your results, so if your model trains faster, there's value there. But the choice of scaling range probably isn't as important as the choice of activation function wrt training time. Recent-ish results have found ReLU units to work well to train the model quickly because sigmoidal units rapidly develop near-0 gradient. Dropout and other regularization methods can improve model generalization.

Comment: I've implemented drop-out. But for a three layer network dropout is not state of the art, correct?

Comment: State of the art in this context would be some refinement of having several convolutional layers, a fully connected layer, dropout and ReLU units.